# Draw circle around imperfect circular objects

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have this image of an eye where I want to get the center of the pupil:
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjioe.jpg)

I applied adaptive threshold as well as laplacian to the image using this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\input\left.jpg',0)
image = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(th,cv2.CV_64F)

cv2.imshow('output', laplacian)
cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output.jpg', laplacian)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

and the resulting image looks like this: [Resulting image by applying adaptive threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPMi3.jpg)

I want to draw a circle around the smaller inner circle and get its center. I've tried using contours and circular hough transform but it does not correctly detect any circles in the image.

Here is my code for Circular Hough Transform:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output.jpg',0)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(255,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here is the code for applying contour:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output.jpg',0)

_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, 1, 2)

cnt = contours[0]

(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
center = (int(x),int(y))
radius = int(radius)
img = cv2.circle(img,center,radius,(0,255,255),2)

cv2.imshow('contour', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The resulting image of this code exactly looks like the image wherein I applied adaptive threshold. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me solve my problem. I've been stuck with this for a while now. Also, if any of you guys can suggest a better way to detect the center of the pupil besides this method, I would also really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought would be to use the Hough transform like you're doing. But another method might be template matching like this. This assumes you know the approximate radius of the pupil in the image, you can try to build a template.

```
import skimage
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = skimage.io.imread('Wjioe.jpg')

#just use grayscale, but you could make separate template for each r,g,b channel 
img = np.mean(img, axis=2)

(M,N) = img.shape
mm = M-20
nn = N-20
template = np.zeros([mm,nn])

## Create template ##

#darkest inner circle (pupil)
(rr,cc) = skimage.draw.circle(mm/2,nn/2,4.5, shape=template.shape)
template[rr,cc]=-2

#iris (circle surrounding pupil)
(rr,cc) = skimage.draw.circle(mm/2,nn/2,8, shape=template.shape)
template[rr,cc] = -1

#Optional - pupil reflective spot (if centered)
(rr,cc) = skimage.draw.circle(mm/2,nn/2,1.5, shape=template.shape)
template[rr,cc] = 1

plt.imshow(template)

normccf = skimage.feature.match_template(img, template,pad_input=True)

#center pixel
(i,j) = np.unravel_index( np.argmax(normccf), normccf.shape)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.plot(j,i,'r*')
```

[image: normccf]

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not really familiar with using skimage. I still need to study it but this way seems really good. I have a question though, will this method work for generally for all eye images like this one? The positioning of the eye as well as the size of the image will not vary but I am planning to use this code to detect pupils of different people in images taken by a camera. If I just specify a 'safe' approximation of the pupil radius, do you think it would work?

Comment: It should work pretty well for different eye images with pupil / iris of the same size. However you might need to tweak the template, for example if there is no camera flash reflection in the pupil then remove the bright spot in the center. Also please accept /upvote the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Also the radii of the various parts. But the positioning of the eye in the image shouldn't matter as long as it's mostly visible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I marked your answer as the correct since it actually did the job. However, since I'm only familiar in using opencv I had a hard time understanding the code (although I'll try to study it in the future). I was able to achieve the same thing by combining different thresholding available in opencv. But I'm experiencing (again) some difficulties. I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look into it if you have the time.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question that I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045932/opencv-thresholding-code-working-in-python2-7windows-but-not-working-raspberry

Comment: Well that's funny b/c I don't know much about opencv. But it looks like you got your answer on that other question and you're on your way. good luck

Answer (score 2):

try to apply edge detection instead of shareholding after filtering of original image and then apply hough circle

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a 3 channel color for a gray-scale image. Based on my test it will only read the first value in that tuple. Because the first value in your other colors (in the middle code) starts with 255, it draws a full white circle and because the first value in your last color (in your last code) starts with 0, it draws a full black circle which you can't see.
Just change your color values to a 1 channel color (an int between 0 and 255) and you'll be fine.