# Opencv thresholding code working in python2.7(Windows) but not working Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I have this python code that applies a series thresholding to an image of an eye so that it would it would be able to detect the pupil. I wrote this code using python 2.7 in windows 10. It actually worked great since I was able to get my desired output.

Here is the code that I wrote in windows 10:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\input\left.jpg',0)
image = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

#Apply Adaptive Threshold with Laplacian
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(th,cv2.CV_64F)

cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output1.jpg', laplacian)

#Apply Inverse Binary Threshold

binthresh = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output1.jpg',0)

ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(laplacian,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output2.jpg', thresh2)

#Apply First Otsu's Threshold

otsuthresh1 = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output2.jpg',0)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(otsuthresh1,(5,5),0)

ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output3.jpg', th3)

#Apply Gaussian Blur
gaussblur = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output3.jpg',0)

blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gaussblur,(5,5),0)

cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output4.jpg', blur2)
#Apply Second Otsu's Threshold
otsuthresh2 = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output4.jpg',0)

blur3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(otsuthresh2,(5,5),0)

ret4,th4 = cv2.threshold(blur3,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)


#Apply Circular Hough Transform
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(th4,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(th4,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(100,100,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(th4,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,50,100),3)

cv2.imshow('combined', th4)
cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output5.jpg', th4)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is a screenshot of all the outputs of the code (including the original input image):

[image: Here is a screenshot of the series of outputs of the code:]

I tried running this same code in my raspberry pi, I just changed the file path of the input image as well as where to store the output images.

Here is the code that I ran in my Raspberry Pi:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('/home/pi/IPD/images/image1.jpg',0)
image = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

#Apply Adaptive Threshold with Laplacian
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(th,cv2.CV_64F)


#Apply Inverse Binary Threshold

binthresh = cv2.imread('/home/pi/IPD/temp/output1.jpg',0)

ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(binthresh,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imwrite('/home/pi/IPD/temp/output2.jpg', thresh2)

#Apply First Otsu's Threshold

otsuthresh1 = cv2.imread('/home/pi/IPD/temp/output2.jpg',0)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(otsuthresh1,(5,5),0)

ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imwrite('/home/pi/IPD/temp/output3.jpg', th3)

#Apply Gaussian Blur
gaussblur = cv2.imread('/home/pi/IPD/temp/output3.jpg',0)

blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gaussblur,(5,5),0)

cv2.imwrite('/home/pi/IPD/temp/output4.jpg', blur2)
#Apply Second Otsu's Threshold
otsuthresh2 = cv2.imread('C/home/pi/IPD/temp/output4.jpg',0)

blur3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(otsuthresh2,(5,5),0)

ret4,th4 = cv2.threshold(blur3,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)


#Apply Circular Hough Transform
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(th4,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(th4,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(100,100,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(th4,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,50,100),3)

cv2.imshow('combined', th4)
cv2.imwrite('/home/pi/IPD/images/final.jpg', th4)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However I get the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/IPD/mod4.py", line 18, in 
    ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(binthresh,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
error: /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:269: error: (-215) m.dims >= 2 in function Mat**

Actually, I've also encountered this error when I first wrote the code in windows 10 but I solved it by writing the newly thresholded image and just loading it again (as you can see in my code. I know it's an inefficient way) so that I can apply a new threshold to it. I've tried searching for possible explanations why this might be and I figured it has something to do with how many channels the signal I'm inputting is (I think). However, I'm still new to using opencv and image processing in general and I really don't understand the concept really that well (even though I've already researched it).

If you guys can help me and point me in the right direction, I would be really grateful. And also if you guys can suggest how I can avoid storing the newly thresholded image and loading it again (which is really an inefficient way of going about this) without causing any errors, I would really, really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post the error that you're encountering when you *don't* write the images and then read them in again? Also, have you verified that the first binary image is being written correctly on your pi?

Comment: It's the same error as I've posted above. The problem always points out the line where I apply the inverse binary threshold. Yes. There was one time that I was able to run the code, and it generated the first 4 output images but it did not generate the output with the circular hough transform. But I was only able to do it once. I haven't been able to replicate it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted 2 errors, I hope those are the only 2.

1) In your first code you have:

```
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(th,cv2.CV_64F)

cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output1.jpg', laplacian)

#Apply Inverse Binary Threshold

binthresh = cv2.imread('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output1.jpg',0)

ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(laplacian,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

here you are doing the laplacian operator and saving it in a CV_64F image (doubles), but threshold **ONLY** takes CV_8U or CV_32F. Here you have two options, one is to change this 64F to 32F or to use the function [normalize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize) and convert it to 8U image. Something like:

```
cv2.normalize(laplacian, output1, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)
```

2) In the second code you are missing:

```
cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\User\Documents\module4\output\output1.jpg', laplacian)
```

So, you are not saving such an image, thus you are not loading it either... no image, an error jumps out.

General suggestions, always use `imshow` to see what is going on until what point. Use relative paths for the saving and loading of the temp images, this way you only change the input path.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try out your suggestions.

Comment: @Swagayema if you still have the error just posted, to try to figure something else out :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Using the cv2.normalize did the trick. Changing 64F to 32F did not process correctly and just showed blank images. I was also able to edit my code without writing and loading the output images once I used the cv2.normalize. The code also ran correctly in my Raspberry Pi (although I'm now having problems with applying the circular hough transform part. it keeps on having an error about the object not having an attribute 'HOUGH_GRADIENT') But when I take out the CHT part, the thresholding works correctly albeit a little different compared to my original output.

Comment: @Swagayema float images are displayed as if the values go from 0-1 (anything after 1 is white), you can always convert the images to CV_8U afterwards using normalize or scale the values to 0-1

Comment: @appi55 Thank you so much for the information. I'll try to research more on that topic. :)